# The last attempted delivery failed with the following error: javax.jms.TransactionRolledBackException:

Tags: ejb-3.0, ibm-mq, rad, websphere-7

I am using websphere MQ and WAS .

i  created Message driven bean , in oncall method i am doing business layer stuffs to retrieve data from database but i am getting error as i mentioned in title
i am using cod like here

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.schema.ticketservices_v1");
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

            RetrieveTicketRequest retrieveTicketRequest = (RetrieveTicketRequest) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileInputStream("D://request4.xml"));
            System.out.println(retrieveTicketRequest.getCorrelationID());
            TicketRemarksBindingImpl bindingImpl = new TicketBindingImpl();
            RetrieveTicketResponse retrieveTicketResponse = bindingImpl.retrieve(retrieveTicketRequest);
```

I am able to retrieve data expected from database but getting following exception

```
    [10/10/12 11:39:36:778 IST] 000000ea RegisteredRes E   WTRN0063E: An illegal attempt to commit a one phase capable resource with existing two phase capable resources has occurred.
[10/10/12 11:39:36:779 IST] 000000ea RegisteredRes E   WTRN0086I: XAException encountered during prepare phase for transaction 0000013A494AE71F000000020000000AA2E8C1F524D2F1D345141C905AF81B4416CCDB030000013A494AE71F000000020000000AA2E8C1F524D2F1D345141C905AF81B4416CCDB0300000001. Local resources follow.
[10/10/12 11:39:36:779 IST] 000000ea JTAResourceBa I   WTRN0089I: LocalTransactionWrapper@:54ae54ae  localTransaction:com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbSpiLocalTransactionImpl@54c554c5  enlisted:trueHas Tran Rolled Back = false  registeredForSynctruemcWrapper.hashcode()1415009367: Vote: none.
[10/10/12 11:39:36:780 IST] 000000ea JTAResourceBa I   WTRN0089I: com.ibm.mq.connector.xa.XARWrapper@53985398: Vote: commit.
[10/10/12 11:39:36:814 IST] 00000024 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0524I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec jms/testMDBspec (com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application TicketRemarkServiceEJBProjectEAR#TicketRemarkServiceEJBProject.jar#TicketMDB is deactivated.
[10/10/12 11:39:36:815 IST] 00000024 SibMessage    W   [:] CWWMQ0007W: The message endpoint TicketRemarkServiceEJBProjectEAR#TicketRemarkServiceEJBProject.jar#TicketMDB has been paused by the system.  Message delivery failed to the endpoint more than 0 times.  The last attempted delivery failed with the following error: javax.jms.TransactionRolledBackException: 
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.WorkImpl.callDeliveryFailed(WorkImpl.java:464)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.WorkImpl.xaStateChanged(WorkImpl.java:421)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.xa.XAObservable.update(XAObservable.java:120)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.xa.XARWrapper.rollback(XARWrapper.java:444)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.JTAXAResourceImpl.rollback(JTAXAResourceImpl.java:363)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.RegisteredResources.deliverOutcome(RegisteredResources.java:1589)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.RegisteredResources.distributeOutcome(RegisteredResources.java:1926)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.RegisteredResources.distributeRollback(RegisteredResources.java:2579)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.internalRollback(TransactionImpl.java:1951)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.internalRollback(TransactionImpl.java:1914)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.coreStage2CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1101)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.stage2CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1128)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:989)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:919)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.commit(TranStrategy.java:927)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.postInvoke(TranStrategy.java:230)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.postInvoke(TransactionControlImpl.java:570)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvoke(EJSContainer.java:4558)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.afterDelivery(MessageEndpointHandler.java:1449)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.invokeMessageEndpointMethod(MessageEndpointHandler.java:806)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointHandler.java:767)
    at $Proxy118.afterDelivery(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.WorkImpl.run(WorkImpl.java:333)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.work.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:399)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

Answer (score 3):

> An illegal attempt to commit a one phase capable resource with
>   existing two phase capable resources has occurred.

This is what you should be looking at.

Make sure all the resources are XA capable and are configured to work with XA, my guess is that the DB is configured with XA and MQ is not.

Also, there is an option to use **one** non XA resource in a XA transaction, it is called Last Participant Support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Then how to make this XA capable..for DB as well as MQ..??

Comment: For the DB it depends on which Driver you selected for the JDBC Provider. For MQ I do not know, but searching websphere MQ XA gives a lot of results.